# Ember renders html via link-to, but json via typing url in browser

Tags: ember.js

This doesn't happen locally in development, but after deploying to Heroku, if I navigate to my app's root page it loads fine and if I click the "posts" link it loads all my posts in html. But if I navigate to the same page by typing the url in the browser's url input, or even if I simply click the refresh button, it loads json instead of html. Inspecting the request, I see that it sends no query params (so the json is not paginated) and there is no Content-Type in the request headers.

**Update**

I tried namespacing my routes in rails with "api" and updating the apiURL in config/environment.js in ember. Now, just like above, it works fine if I click links, but not if I type the url or refresh, but now instead of loading json, nothing is loaded and the error on the back end is `No route matches [GET] "/posts"`. So I guess the link_to's in ember aren't inserting "api" to the url

The namespace is not important to me, I just thought it might help. But perhaps it reveals what my underlying issue is to someone?

Also, I found this [EMBER direct route URL access dont load data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324203/ember-direct-route-url-access-dont-load-data?rq=1), and it seems eerily similar to my problem so I'll post some of my relevant code:

```
// routes/posts.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    page: {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    limit: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model(params) {
    return this.store.query('post', {
      filter: {
        name: "categories.name",
        op: "!=",
        val: "Projects"
      },
      limit: params.limit,
      page: params.page,
      includes: [
        "tags",
        "categories"
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

```
// routes/post.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_id);
  }
});
```

**Update 2**

Here is my Rails' routes file

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :categories
    resources :comments
    resources :posts
  end

  get "*path", :to => redirect("index.html")
end
```

Comment: Are you using any Heroku buildpacks?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit how you serve your ember assets

Comment: I just place them in the public folder of the Rails app. They're not on a CDN if that's what you're asking. To answer @mwp, I am not using a Heroku Buildpack. Just the ruby one that is chosen automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I never really figured out the vanilla way to do solve this. I do believe the issue is with Rails (specifically the router) and not the server, but I could be wrong. What leads me to believe this is this bit in the Ember guides https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/specifying-url-type/#toc_history, specifically:

> Keep in mind that your server must serve the Ember app from all the URLs defined in your Router.map function. In other words, if your user directly navigates to /posts/new, your server must be configured to serve your Ember app in response.

I think by "server", the guide means, in my case, my rails api. In any case, the way I eventually solved this was by happening upon the ember-cli-rails gem and the corresponding ember-cli-rails-addon which basically abstracts away a lot of the configuring of these two frameworks to work with each other and as a bonus integrates well with Heroku for easy deployments. I would have liked to solve this without a magic plugin, but whatever. It works now.

Comment: [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48143716/2948109) someone suggests to deploy FE and API as two separate heroku apps.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an issue with web-server's (nginx or whatever do you use on heroku) configuration - it returns API response instead of serving frontend app.

I can give an example of correct nginx configuration for ember app:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jira-stats.domain;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jira-stats.domain/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jira-stats.domain/privkey.pem;
        server_name jira-stats.domain;
        root /path/to/dist;

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

        # Deny all . files
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
        }

        index index.html
        access_log off;
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript image/png image/gif image/jpeg image/jpg;

        location / {
                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}
```

In this config `location` part is very important. It instructs nginx to serve `index.html` if requested path is not a file. Ember's router will then parse url and render correct route.

You also need to move API to sub-domain or port different from 80/443. From your question I think that URL and port of frontend and backend are the same.

Comment: I have no idea how to edit the web server's config on Heroku. I updated my question with some of my code on the chance that it's not a web server problem and is an ember problem.

Answer (score 1):

The very important question here is how you've deployed your app to heroku.
If you bundle your backend (your rails API) and your frontend (your ember app) before you deploy or not.

If you bundle them your rails backend is not only responsible for serving the API but also for serving your ember app. This means That all ember files (`js`, `css`) will be served by rails as static assets.

Since ember does client site routing this means that your rails backend must serve the `index.html` whenever it encouters a HTTP GET request with an unknown URL. So basically your `index.html` becames your `404` file, except that rails should always respond with HTTP 200 OK.

Comment: Hey @Lux, I am building my Ember app for production into the public folder of my Rail's app. Based on some internet research I think I'm now "serving the index.html whenever it encounters an HTTP GET request with an unknown URL" like you say, but its still not working. Links still work (like before), but now when I reload or navigate to a url directly, the page is blank and it throws `UnrecognizedURLError: /index.html` in the browser's console. So I've updated my question with my routes file. Can you take a look, I will be happy to mark your answer correct if we can get this working!

Comment: have you considered to join the ember community discord server and ask for help in the #help channel?

Comment: I've never heard of it. Can you link me?